# Style 4th instance using CSS

Tags: css

I have four tabs created by a piece of coding and I would like to style the fourth tab differently. Unfortunately there is no specific classes or IDs assigned individually to the list elements and no easy way of achieving this.

Is it possible to style the fourth instance of a list object using CSS alone?

This is an example of the coding that is created by the script:

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
   <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-5310-0-0">Description</a></li>
   <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-5310-0-1">Features</a></li>
   <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-5310-0-2">Specification</a></li>
   <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-5310-0-3">360° Interactive Virtual View</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`:nth-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) pseudo class in your selector:

```
ul li:nth-child(4) { /* ... */ }
```

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) is good; IE < 9 is the only (admittedly not insignificant) issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
ul li:first-child + li + li + li
```

This probably has the best browser coverage you can get in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

on newer browser you could do

```
ul li:nth-child(4);
```

on older browser (`IE7/8`) you could set a style for

```
ul li + li + li + li { /* assign a style */ }
```

and then revert it on next list-item

```
ul li + li + li + li + li { /* revert the previous style */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer the last item as opposed specifically to the fourth you could alternatively use `nth-last-child` or `last-child`:

```
ul li:nth-last-child(1) { ... };
```

or

```
ul li:last-child { ... };
```